# Where to find Unicode 5 characters from specific category?

Tags: unicode, characters

I need to list all characters from the categories ID Start and ID Continue in Unicode. Where could I do that for a specific version of Unicode (in this case, Unicode 5)?

I think the site https://codepoints.net doesn't allow doing this for specific Unicode version.

Comment: Does [Unicode 5.0.0](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/) help? See the links on the left side.

Comment: @DavidPostill Hum, yeah, I've read it, but I'm not sure that I'll easily understand the linked documents. I want to go straight to the IDS and IDC characters, or just know if they were not changed since Unicode 2.0...

Comment: I can't really help any more because I don't know what IDS and IDC categories are so I don't completely understand the question. :/

Comment: [Proposal to redefine the scope of Ideographic Description Sequences and to encode four additional Ideographic Description Characters](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2009/09171-n3643-ideo-desc.pdf) and maybe some earlier version of [CJKRadicals-9.0.0.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/9.0.0/ucd/CJKRadicals.txt)

Comment: @JosefZ Sorry... I forgot to specify that IDS would be ID Start and IDC would be ID Continue. They would fit with ECMAScript 3 or 4 specification grammar for Identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Unicode® Standard Annex #31 (Unicode identifier and pattern syntax)](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/), `ID_Start` and `ID_Continue` character categories are derived from the Unicode [`General_Category`](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/3.0-Update/UnicodeData-3.0.0.html#General%20Category) (read whole [UnicodeData File Format](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/3.0-Update/UnicodeData-3.0.0.html) and [Unicode character database](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/3.0-Update/UnicodeCharacterDatabase-3.0.0.html) articles).

See [Table 2. Properties for Lexical Classes for Identifiers](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/#Table_Lexical_Classes_for_Identifiers) (digest of):

> - `ID_Start` characters are derived from the Unicode General_Category of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, titlecase letters, modifier
>     letters, other letters, letter numbers, plus `Other_ID_Start`, minus
>     `Pattern_Syntax` and `Pattern_White_Space` code points.
>
>   - In set notation:
>   - `[[:L:][:Nl:][:Other_ID_Start:]--[:Pattern_Syntax:]--[:Pattern_White_Space:]]`
> - `ID_Continue` characters include `ID_Start` characters, plus characters having the Unicode General_Category of nonspacing marks,
>     spacing combining marks, decimal number, connector punctuation, plus
>     `Other_ID_Continue` , minus `Pattern_Syntax` and `Pattern_White_Space` code
>     points.
>
>   - In set notation:
>   - `[[:ID_Start:][:Mn:][:Mc:][:Nd:][:Pc:][:Other_ID_Continue:]--[:Pattern_Syntax:]--[:Pattern_White_Space:]]`

We can see reference to `Other_ID_Start`, `Other_ID_Continue`, `Pattern_Syntax` and `Pattern_White_Space` here; for instance:

> The exact list of characters covered by the `Other_ID_Start` and
>   `Other_ID_Continue` properties **depends on the version of Unicode**.
>   For more information, see Unicode Standard Annex #44, “Unicode
>   Character Database” [[UAX44]](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr41/tr41-19.html#UAX44).

Parse [`UnicodeData.txt`](http://unicode.org/Public/5.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt), apply valid regex(es) created from above *set notation*. Apply to proper version of `UnicodeData.txt`, browsing from [Index of /Public](http://unicode.org/Public/).

```
 http://unicode.org/Public/5.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt
                           ↑ ↑ ↑
```

Comment: Very much thanks thanks, I think with your help I'm able to get the code points for `ID_START` and `ID_CONTINUE`, I'll also try to fit it with ECMAScript 4...